# Question related to the spectrum of a bounded operator

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

If $A$ is a bounded linear operator on a Banach space $X$ and $\lambda\in \sigma(A)$, is it true that for all $\epsilon>0$, there is $ x\in X$ and $||x||=1$ such that

$$ ||(A-\lambda I) x|| <\epsilon \ ?$$

If not, is it true if we consider $X$ a Hilbert space and $A$ self adjoint? Thanks.

Comment: Seems to me you're asking whether the spectrum of an operator can consist only its residual spectrum. In the self-adjoint case, the spectral theorem rules this out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shift operator $Se_n = e_{n+1}$, where $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis on a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is an isometry, despite not being invertible. As for your second question, the residual spectrum of a normal operator is empty (Exercise 79 of Halmos's *A Hilbert Space Problem Book*). This would imply that every element of the spectrum is either in the point spectrum (an eigenvalue) or in the approximate point spectrum (the condition you want).

Edit: Citation found.